# How could I bind the ajax data with Vue

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

I use Jquery ajax load data which form outside API is success, `v-for` text has no problem too.

> Vue

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el:'.inlinePoetry',
  data:{
      PoetryList:[]
  },
  created:function(){
      var self = this;
      $.ajax({
          url: "api/poetry.json",
          dataType:'json',
          type: 'GET',
          data: "data",
          cache: false,
          ifModified: true,
          success: function getData(data){
              self.PoetryList = data.PoetryList;
          },
          error: function(result){ console.log('error'); }
      })
  }

})
```

> html

```
<div class="inline_frame" v-for="(item,index) in PoetryList">
    <div class="inline_content" :id="Poetryid">
        <div class="letter">
            <div class="letter-t">Title</div>
            <div>{{item.letterFirst}}</div>
            <div>{{item.letterSecond}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="letter">
            <div class="letter-t">Description</div>
            <div>{{item.letterThird}}</div>
            <div>{{item.letterForth}} <a :href="PoetryLink">click me</a> </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But it's has problem when I bind the href and id in my html tag.
The `:id="Poetryid"` and `:href="PoetryLink"` use computed.

```
computed:{
  Poetryid:function(){
      // console.log(self.PoetryList.id);
      // return self.PoetryList.id;
      for(var i=0;i<PoetryList.length;i++){
          return PoetryList[i].id
      }
  },
  PoetryLink:function(){
      console.log(self.PoetryList.link);
      return self.PoetryList.link;
  }
}
```

I try to use the `for` to run Poetryid, and my root show `error during evaluation`.
Please give me some advice, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is only going to ever iterate once before returning, provided `PoetryList.length >= 1`

```
// returns return PoetryList[0].id everytime
for(var i=0;i<PoetryList.length;i++){
    return PoetryList[i].id
}
```

Why can't you just access `item.id` directly here?

```
<div class="inline_content" :id="item.id">
```

And the same for `PoetryLink`?

```
<div>{{ item.letterForth }} <a :href="item.link">click me</a> </div>
```